# use a method in a script# class

Tags: script#

I have the following class:

```
[GlobalMethods]
internal static class JQueryTest
{
    static JQueryTest()
    {
        jQuery.OnDocumentReady(delegate
                                   {
                                       test();
                                       test2();
                                   });
    }

    [ScriptName("test")]
    static void test()
    {
        Script.Alert("one");
    }

    [ScriptName("test2")]
    static void test2()
    {
        Script.Alert("two");
    }
}
```

this generates the following javascript:

```
//! Echo.JQueryScript.debug.js
//

(function($) {

Type.registerNamespace('Echo.JQueryScript');

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Echo.JQueryScript._jQueryTest

window.test = function Echo_JQueryScript__jQueryTest$test() {
    alert('one');
}
window.test2 = function Echo_JQueryScript__jQueryTest$test2() {
    alert('two');
}


(function () {
    $(function() {
        test();
        test2();
    });
})();
})(jQuery);

//! This script was generated using Script# v0.7.4.0
```

This is nearly right, I just need semicolons on the end of the window.test=... and window.test2=... lines ie:

```
window.test = function Echo_JQueryScript__jQueryTest$test() {
    alert('one');
};
window.test2 = function Echo_JQueryScript__jQueryTest$test2() {
    alert('two');
};
```

Please could someone else tell me what I should be doing?

Thanks

Stu

Comment: Why do you need semicolons there?

Comment: they're just lines of code - assigning the method to the variable. The javascript only recognises the last entry when run so only displays "two", completely ignoring the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up moving on from Script# which doesn't support angularJS very well in my experience.